# deploy application page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Hi I am new in this development, trying hard to accomplish some task.
I created a sharepoint project, its deploy in layout folder sucessfully, but how can show it on specific page.
i.e: when I run, it usually open the 'server/default.aspx page'.
I want to show my application page at 'server/pages/rpt.aspx'

how can I do this, any reference or help?
by the was its farm.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After deploying the solution, open sharepoint site in sharepoint 2010 desginer.

check this link to set home page

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html